# Problem Grails with many-to-may

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class

I'm programming in Grails 1.3.x, and I have a problem with a query I want to do with 2 tables related to "many to many. "

I have a table called "Group" and a "Person. " I have a group name, but I need to list or have the first person from that group. Something like ..

```
Person.findAllByGroups(?)
```

I put here? I called good or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
def group = Group.findByName('groupName')
def personList = Person.findAll('from Person as p WHERE ? IN ELEMENTS(p.groups)',[group])
```

Comment: Was reversed,

   def personList = Person.findAll("from Person as u where :group in elements (u.groups)," [group: group])

Thanks!!!!